# Debugging advice for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a rails Event Registration application that is giving me some issues. I have a user that wants to register for an event but when she tries to register she gets an error "Something went wrong..." (generic rails production error). I have not been able to replicate the issue at all (even on other browsers) and many people have registered for the same since. Looking in the Heroku rails console I can see that it did not save her in the database.

NewRelic is showing that this is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `registrations_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f603c0cfe38>:0x007f602c773240>
URL /events/6/registrations
HTTP referrer   http://.../events/6/registrations/new
```

I can see that it happened a few times as she tried to do it. She also tried on another event and had the same issue.

Here is my create method:

```
def create
    @current_event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @registration = @current_event.registrations.new(registration_parameters)

    # Checking that there are still seats available
    if (@current_event.registrations.count < @current_event.total_number_registrants)
        # Checking that the user hasn't already registered
        if (Registration.where(event_id: @current_event.id).where(email: @registration.email).count == 0)
            respond_to do |format|
                if @registration.save
                    EventMailer.new_registration_notification(@registration, @current_event).deliver
                    Recipient.create :first_name => @registration.first_name, :last_name => @registration.last_name, :email => @registration.email, :netID => @registration.netID, :event_id => @registration.event_id, :mailing_id => nil
                    format.html { redirect_to event_path(@current_event), notice: 'Registration was successful' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @registration}
                else
                    format.html { render :new }
                    format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        else
            redirect_to event_path(@current_event), notice: 'This email is already registered'
        end
    else
        redirect_to event_path(@current_event), notice: 'There are no seats available'
    end
end
```

Any advice on how to fix an error that you can't replicate but have trace for. I don't even see where 'registrations_path' would be being called.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhere in the view template. I suppose your registration resource is nested under the events so registrations_path doesn't exist in routes but rather is something like events_registration_path

How does your event show template look like?

Comment: I am waiting to hear where exactly the error happened in the process, but I did do a 'Find in files' search in sublime for 'registrations_path' but I do not see any, only event_registrations_path. Could it have something to do with the form? It must be happening before the redirect since it is not saving to database, also there were seats and the email was unique. Show method is very long but I can work on getting it on here

Comment: Also, any idea why it would happen to only one user (that I know of) and not the others who have registered. I can't even replicate the error but for some reason this user can't register for any events

Comment: That is most peculiar if the method is not there anywhere. It must be coming from somewhere. Let us know at what point the error occurs when you hear back.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I've never debugged an error like this! I think it is only happening with the one user based on logs. She is using OS X 10.10.4 with Safari which I tried using and still couldn't replicate. She was on the event (event#show), clicked register (registration#new), then filled out the form and clicked Submit (registration#create - no view but should redirect). So somewhere between #new and #create without it saving to the database. Strange!

Comment: It's gotta be one of the redirect paths. Have you possibly got your code on Github or elsewhere so I could have a look? Bit hard to shoot in the dark!